# MDBootsrap Form Input text overlapping label & label not working as expected onClick

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I am trying to add a material design bootstrap form login from [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/basic/).

The form is displaying like so:

[image: login screen]

But when I click on one of the input controls, the text is overlapping, & the label isn't moving above the input field as expected.

Here is the expected result:

[image]

And here is the actual result

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Form -->
<form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" action="#!">

  <!-- Email -->
  <div class="md-form">
    <input type="email" id="materialLoginFormEmail" class="form-control">
    <label for="materialLoginFormEmail">E-mail</label>
  </div>

  <!-- Password -->
  <div class="md-form">
    <input type="password" id="materialLoginFormPassword" class="form-control">
    <label for="materialLoginFormPassword">Password</label>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div>
      <!-- Forgot password -->
      <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Sign in button -->
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block my-4 waves-effect z-depth-0" type="submit">Sign
    in</button>

  <!-- Register -->
  <p>Not a member?
    <a href="">Register</a>
  </p>

</form>
<!-- Form -->
```

And here are some values in my *angular.json*:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/mdb.scss",
          "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
          "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
          "node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
          "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
          "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"
        ]
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing, & why the form isn't working as expected? I've copied the code exactly from the tutorial I linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use jQuery code, here is MDB Angular version:

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/forms/basic/

For the label to work correctly you need to add `mdbInput` directive to the input element.